# How to use Jackson with Generics

Tags: java, generics, serialization, jackson

I have the following object structure:

```
public class Animal<T> implements IMakeSound<T>
public class Dog<T> extends Animal<T>
public class Cat<T> extends Animal<T>
```

I want to serialize and de-serialize my object using jackson.
The problem is that in the Json I am getting a LinkedHashmap in the T and the de-sirializtion is to the base object Animal.

When I am adding restriction to the T i.e.  than it works perfectly because of the Jackson annotations

```
@JsonSubTypes({
   @Type(value = PuffyTail.class, name = "puffyTail"),
   @Type(value = StraightTail.class, name = "straightTail") })
class Tail {
...
```

But that is not the behavior that I wanted - I don't use < X extends Y >.

Is there a way to work with java generics and get the right object that was serialized?
Is there a way to accomplish it without annotations?

Comment: Because generics are compile time type erased you need to provide hints to Jackson as to how to create generic types.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a TypeReference when reading the value from your ObjectMapper in order to parse the correctly typed object:

```
Cat<PuffyTail> fluffyKitty = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString,
        new TypeReference<Cat<PuffyTail>>(){});
```