# How to use Jackson with nested Generics?

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I use Retrofit and Jackson.There is a POJO like this:

```
public class QuotationHttpResult<T> {
    private int code;
    private Result result;

    public T getData(){
        return result == null ? null : result.getData();
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Result getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(Result result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    class Result{
        private T data;

        public T getData() {
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

The filed data is what I need,sometimes is a POJO,sometimes is a List.
When it is a list,jackson just convert data to a LinkedHashMap even though I use the TypeReference:
The Json String is :

```
 {"code": 0,
     "result": {
         "data": [
            {
            "id": "1000",
            "name": "tecent"
            }, 
            {
            "id": "1001",
            "name": "alibaba"
            }
         ]
       }
    }
```

the convert code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
QuotationHttpResult<List<MyClass>> result = mapper.readValue(json,new TypeReference<QuotationHttpResult<List<MyClass>>>() {});
```

MyClass is simple:

```
class MyClass{
    String id;
    String name;
}
```

I see this question, [How to use Jackson with Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810356/how-to-use-jackson-with-generics) , and everything goes well when I don't nest generics, but how can I do when generics is nested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should make `Result` static ([more info](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/08/entry_411.html)) or move it out of `QuotationHttpResult`, so jackson can see it `data` type. Because of that you will have to make it generic `Result<T>`. you also have to add getters and setters to your `MyClass` POJO or add annotations for jackson.

Here is demo:

```
public class QuotationHttpResult<T> {
    private int code;

    private Result<T> result;

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Result<T> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(Result<T> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public static class Result<T>{
        private T data;

        public T getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String json = " {\"code\": 0,\n" +
            "     \"result\": {\n" +
            "         \"data\": [\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "            \"id\": \"1000\",\n" +
            "            \"name\": \"tecent\"\n" +
            "            }, \n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "            \"id\": \"1001\",\n" +
            "            \"name\": \"alibaba\"\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "         ]\n" +
            "       }\n" +
            "    }";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    QuotationHttpResult<MyClass> result = mapper.readValue(json,new TypeReference<QuotationHttpResult<List<MyClass>>>() {});
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: The `data` field here wont be of type `MyClass` though. It'll be `ArrayList` breaking all type safety.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with [Custom Deserializer for Jackson](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization). I think it's the best way for problematic deserialization...